# Simplify an expression with ArcCos

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can simplify this expression with Mathematica ?

```
Sin[1/2*ArcCos[x]]^2
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6):

```
Sin[1/2*ArcCos[x]]^2 // TrigReduce
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you

Comment: Alternatively (but not as succinctly), `Sin[1/2*ArcCos[x]]^2 // TrigToExp // Simplify`